# What is the origin of the theatrical intonation used by Tokyo Disneyland's cast members?

Tags: dialects, intonation

When I had the chance to go on a Jungle Cruise at Tokyo Disneyland, I noticed the skipper talked with sprinkles of prolonged vowels and uncommon rising and falling intonation patterns.

Is this "dialect" original, or was it borrowed from existing profession/region?

**Edit:** you can check video recordings of the ride on Youtube:

- [By a male captain](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p78jDj1GFhc)
- By Captain Sato: [Part 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_bAFroIai-U), [Part 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fkAstbRQTxk)
- [By a female captain](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JU393yfMfio)

Comment: Can you find a video that demonstrates the speech you're talking about? YouTube seems to have several if you search for 東京ディズニーランド ジャングルクルーズ. For example, here's [one of Captain Satō](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_bAFroIai-U) (which, to me, sounds a lot like the kind of Japanese you'd hear from store clerks stationed along shopping arcades with megaphones to  advertise sales).

Comment: Are you talking about something like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LG1EynIpZ34&feature=related)?

Comment: Doesn't seem all that unusual to me, it's just showman talk. I don't think it qualifies as a dialect or has any specific origins, but then again I'm not a linguist. :)

Comment: Yes and yes. I've added some more videos to the question. They show the same intonation trait is shared across several captains. And also yes to @deceze. It's certainly not a full-fledged dialect (whatever that may be), but it would be interesting to know any stories behind it, if there is one.

Comment: @ento: To be honest, I don't really hear it either (but I'm far from an expert). They definitely have the typical "いらっしゃいらっしゃ" swagger of market-sellers/street-entertainers, but not to the point where it sounds like a style in its own...

Comment: I agree it's nothing special. Listen to some children's tv in Japanese for this kind of exaggerated "rangey" talking. Sorry I've flagged this for closure.

Comment: At the ride, I was really surprised by the captain's accent, and wondered if she was trying to mimic some tribespeople. After reading everyone's comments, I began to feel really unsure about my ears.. But "It's kind of a child-directed speech (baby talk)" theory does make sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just typical for entertainers who want to capture the attention of the audience.

It's not even unique to Japanese.  When you take the English one in Disney World (Florida) they talk the same way.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QtDKnYCTIh0  The guide in this one does the same thing in English, if not quite as often.  On the rides I've been on, some of them have done it just as often as those Japanese videos.

Comment: Thanks for bringing in a global perspective. I'm getting convinced that it's a cultural universal thing. Here's a clip from [Hong Kong Disneyland's Jungle Cruise](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b954P_LKe1M).